# Iterate to create formulas in spreadsheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am creating an application that creates a spreadsheet and I need to create a table like this

```
      T                 U                  V...                AF
47   =(T20-T$11)/T$12   =(U20-U$11)/U$12   =(V20-V$11)/V$12    =(AF20-AF$11)/AF$12
48   =(T21-T$11)/T$12
49   =(T22-T$11)/T$12
...
69   =(T42-T$11)/T$12                                          =(AF42-AF$11)/AF$12
```

The headers and the index are the locations where I want to put these formulas.

I am been working around this code

```
def fill_formulas_average(row_start,row_end,totals_row,start_col,end_col):

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=tals_row, max_row=totals_row, min_col=start_col, max_col=end_col):
        for cell in row:
            start = cell.column_letter + str(row_start)
            end = cell.column_letter + str(row_end)      
            cell.value = '=({0}-{1})/{0}'.format(start,end)  
            print(cell)
            print(cell.value)


fill_formulas_average(20,11,47,20,50)

<Cell 'Sheet'.T47>
=(T20-T11)/T20
<Cell 'Sheet'.U47>
=(U20-U11)/U20
<Cell 'Sheet'.V47>
=(V20-V11)/V20
<Cell 'Sheet'.W47>
=(W20-W11)/W20
<Cell 'Sheet'.X47>
=(X20-X11)/X20
<Cell 'Sheet'.Y47>
=(Y20-Y11)/Y20
<Cell 'Sheet'.Z47>
=(Z20-Z11)/Z20
<Cell 'Sheet'.AA47>
=(AA20-AA11)/AA20
<Cell 'Sheet'.AB47>
=(AB20-AB11)/AB20
<Cell 'Sheet'.AC47>
=(AC20-AC11)/AC20
<Cell 'Sheet'.AD47>
=(AD20-AD11)/AD20
<Cell 'Sheet'.AE47>
=(AE20-AE11)/AE20
<Cell 'Sheet'.AF47>
=(AF20-AF11)/AF20
```

Could someone help me to adapt my code to get desired output?

Comment: What is the question? Is there an error? Is the file not created properly? Please ask your question clearly...

Comment: Is this a question or some suggestion? If it is a question, please edit the post and mention the issue

Comment: Sorry, the last paragraph was deleted.

Comment: I think, he wants to modify the code to achieve the table. The output he has got so far is for line. He is closed but the last cells created is wrong.

Comment: If `min_row` and `max_row` are the same, then you will over get one row.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code updated to achieve what you mentioned. I have gone by the first part where you mentioned that you need the formulas from row 47 till row 69 and columns T to AF. The naming convention is left as is, but I have indicated what data should be sent in case you need to change this. Note that, as is in your first output table, the `$11` and `$12` are not changing.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data_file='test1.xlsx'
# Load the entire workbook.
wb = load_workbook(data_file)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]

def fill_formulas_average(row_start,row_end,totals_row,start_col,end_col):

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=totals_row, max_row=totals_row + (row_end - row_start), min_col=start_col, max_col=end_col):
        for cell in row:
            start = cell.column_letter + str(row_start + row[0].row - totals_row)
            cell.value = '=({0}-{1}$11)/{2}$12'.format(start,cell.column_letter,cell.column_letter)  
            print(cell)
            print(cell.value)

fill_formulas_average(20,42,47,20,32)
# Ref for inputs
# 20 (row_start) - This will be the first row which will be part of the formula - 20th row
# 42 (row_end) - This will be the last row till when we will need to build forumlas - So, data is available from 20th row to 42nd row
# 47 (totals_row) - This is row from where the first formula will be added. From the 47th row onwards
# 20 (start_col) - This is column from where first formula will be added. From the 20th column (=col T) onwards
# 32 (end_col) - This is end column will where formula will be added. Till the 32nd column (=col AF)

wb.save('test2.xlsx')
```

**Output** I used Formulas -> Formula Auditing -> Show formulas so that you can see the formulas for all cells

[image: Output in excel - show formulas]

Answer (score 0):

```
def minus_and_div(avg_totals_row,letter1,letter2,start_col,end_col):
    '''
    To fill table T47 to AF69
    To generate this <Cell 'Sheet'.T47>
                     =(T20-T11)/T12
    to this          <Cell 'Sheet'.AF47>
                     =(AF20-AF11)/AF12
    input values are 47,20,12,20,32
    One function per line
    '''
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=avg_totals_row, max_row=avg_totals_row, min_col=start_col, max_col=end_col):
        for cell in row:
            start = cell.column_letter + str(letter1)  
            middle = cell.column_letter
            end = cell.column_letter + str(letter2)  
            cell.value = '=({0}-{1})/{2}'.format(start, middle, end)
```